# reading and analyzing a text file with bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, echo

I want to read a log file and want to extract 5-6 number digit that is written right next after the keyword "salary". And then want to analyze if the salary is above 2000. If there is even one above 2000, it is a MNC otherwise unknown. After writing the salary, the line ends mostly but sometimes there is an email option.

My script currently looks like this.

```
salary=$(grep -o 'salary [1-9][0-9]\+$' tso.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+')

echo $salary

if [ $salary >  2000 ]; then echo "it is mnc....."; else ":it is unknown....."; fi
```

Comment: Maybe `salary=$(grep -oP 'salary *0*\K[1-9][0-9]*' tso.txt)` and then  `if [ $salary -gt  0 ]; then`?

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: I second @JamesBrown here, edit your question with respective samples of input and expected output to make question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a simple `awk` like this:

```sh
awk '
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($(i-1) == "salary" && $i+0 > 2000) {
         mnc = 1
         exit
      }
}
END {
   print (mnc ? "it is mnc....." : "it is unknown.....")
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfect. I have not explored the awk keyword. Still relatively new to me. Any good document that you could recommend for awk?

Comment: You can start with this [awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be using a GNU `grep`, you can get the salary value directly with `grep -oP 'salary *0*\K[1-9][0-9]*'` and then you can check the salary with `if [ $salary -gt  0 ]`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/O03T1t):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tso='salary 23000'
salary=$(grep -oP 'salary *0*\K[1-9][0-9]*' <<< "$tso")
echo $salary # => 23000

if [ $salary -gt  0 ]; then
  echo "it is mnc.....";
else
  echo "it is unknown....."; 
fi
# => it is mnc.....
```